# How to set up load balancing with java 8 collection parallel stream processing?

Tags: java, multithreading, parallel-processing, java-8, java-stream

I have a collection with a lot of elements (can be 100 000 or more), time for processing each element varies from 1 sec to 1 minute. **Note** when element process takes 1 second the single CPU core is loaded less then 100% (maybe 5 or 10%).

So I need a following load balancing:

1. Create more threads than CPU core, say cpuCoreNumbers*20
2. start collection processing using `myCollection.parallelStream().forEach()`
3. Monitor CPU load when it less then 100% start next element processing, when CPU loading is 100% stop adding next elements and wait until load is less then 80% (for example).

The main idea is to create and use more threads then CPU cores for "lite collection processing" and reduce threads when "heavy" element start processing.

Is it posssible to setup load balancing like that during Java 8 parallel stream processing?

Comment: In a word, NO. The JVM is a Virtual machine. Your application has no access to the actual machine. You could use the management APIs to get access to the Java threads but that is a lot of overhead for an application. @Brett Okken mentions some other complications and there are really so many others that it probably isn't worth trying to do what you want.

Answer (score 1):

The [common](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ForkJoinPool.html#commonPool--) fork join pool will be used by default for parallel stream processing. This likely has a number of threads matching the number of available processors.

Monitoring and interpreting CPU utilization is a non-trivial task. This is made complicated by things such as hyper threading, power saving features, turbo boost features, etc.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you have been fooled by whatever kind of tool you used for monitoring. There is no kind of “light processing” mode. When the processing of an element takes only a short time period, it still consumes 100% of a CPU within that time period. Your monitoring tool might smooth the values, e.g. when you have 500 ms of full load followed by 500 ms of no load it might print 50% for a 1 s period. But it would be a completely wrong interpretation to say that the element has been processed using 50% of the CPU.

There is only one scenario where processing of an item doesn’t fully consume the CPU and using more threads can improve the usage of the core: when there is a significant amount of time the item isn’t actually processed, that is, when the thread will be blocked because it waits for another thread or for results of an I/O operation. You should know when your processing task involves I/O or additional thread synchronization (and I assume you mentioned it in the question if that was the case).

But when you process 100000 elements right one after another, it doesn’t matter how long the processing of an individual item takes, since the CPU will be kept busy by processing the next one right after it finished an item. So even the monitoring tool with the smoothing should show 100% CPU load then. If it doesn’t, there is some blocking involved which might be a follow-up operation of your pipeline or a general overhead of the parallelization framework. You then have to analyze the I/O operation(s) to find the right strategy. If a subsequent I/O turns out to be the bottleneck, it doesn’t help to spawn more threads to accelerate the computation.